# Display JSON object nicely with Syntax Hihjlighter

Tags: json, syntaxhighlighter

I'm trying to display a JSON object nicely (this means on several lines with indentation) with Alex Gorbatchev plugin : http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Unfortunately, it all displays on a single line.

I'm using the javascript brush.

I've created a code pen : http://codepen.io/hugsbrugs/pen/XJVjjP?editors=101

```
var json_object = {"hello":{"my_friend":"gérard", "my_dog":"billy"}};

$('#nice-json').html('<pre class="brush: javascript">' + JSON.stringify(json_object) + '</pre>');
SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
```

Please don't give a list of other plugins since I know there is a bunch but I don't want to load additional plugins ... I'd like to achieve it with this plugin.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the optional third parameter of [`JSON.stringify(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#space_argument) which is the space argument.

Change:

```
JSON.stringify(json_object)
```

to:

```
JSON.stringify(json_object, null, '\t')
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwZgRR) is your codepen updated to show the result of the above modifications. The above modification causes your JSON to be pretty printed over multiple lines.

Comment: Awesome ! No plugin, no additional code ! Thank for your fast answer

Answer (score 2):

Try indenting the json with the stringify method.

```
JSON.stringify(json_object, undefined, 2);
```

Comment: Your solution works, well, I accepted War10ck answer's because he was the fastest ! Thanks a lot !